# How to make JavaScript and native code in sync on react-native?

Tags: react-native

I downloaded some react-native code from "https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps" and launch the examples on ios simulator. I got below error showing on IOS simulator. As it suggested how to make javascript and native code in sync?

[image]